# Using union types with a function not accepting arguments as an object

Tags: typescript, types, union-types

Below is a function which uses union-types.

```
type Shape = 
  { kind: 'circle', radius: number } |
  { kind: 'rectangle', w: number, h: number }

const getArea = (shape: Shape) => {     // this works
  switch(shape.kind) {
    case 'circle':
      return Math.PI * shape.radius ** 2
    case 'rectangle':
      return shape.w * shape.h
  }
  throw new Error('Invalid shape')
}

getArea({ kind: 'circle', radius: 10 })
```

It accepts arguments as an object so it works.

But how do I do this when a function does not accept arguments as an object. Please refer the example below

```
type Shape = 
  { (kind: 'circle', ...args: [number]) } |
  { (kind: 'rectangle', ...args: [number, number]) }

const getArea: Shape = (kind, ...args) => {     // this doesn't work
  switch(kind) {
    case 'circle':
      return Math.PI * args[0] ** 2
    case 'rectangle':
      return args[0] * args[1]
  }
  throw new Error('Invalid shape')
}

getArea('circle', 10)
getArea('rectangle', 5, 5)
```

Also, I can go ahead and write it like this

```
const getArea: Shape = (kind: 'update' | 'reset', ...args: [number] | [number, number]) => {
```

but it won't give me full type safety. I want args to change when kind changes as the first example demonstrates.

Or is there any different approach for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it like this

```
const getArea = (...[key, ...args]: ['circle', number] | ['rectangle', number, number]) => {
    switch (key) {
        case 'circle':
            return Math.PI * args[0] ** 2
        case 'rectangle':
            return args[0] * args[1]
    }
    throw new Error('Invalid shape')
}
```

or

```
const getArea = (...args: ['circle', number] | ['rectangle', number, number]) => {
    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'circle':
            return Math.PI * args[1] ** 2
        case 'rectangle':
            return args[1] * args[2]
    }
    throw new Error('Invalid shape')
}
```

Comment: After implementing your solution, it says "A rest element cannot contain a binding pattern."

Comment: Which TypeScript version do you use?

Comment: My TypeScript version is 3.3.1

Comment: Then it's weird, my ts version is 3.2.2 and it works

Comment: They even have an issue for that here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26017

Comment: But thnx for your help. I ended up using your second solution